# Archimedean spiral and length

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

The Archimedean spiral is given as $r=at,\, a>0, \, \text{for}\, t \in [0, \infty).$ I need to calculate the length of the first turn in the third quadrant. I have absolutely no idea how to compute that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

The formula for arc length in polar coordinates is
$$\ell=\int_\pi^{\tfrac{3\pi}2}\sqrt{r^2(t)+r'^2(t)}\,\mathrm dt.$$

Comment: Thank you, I have the formula and also put in what I know. What irritates me is the "third quadrant" part...

Comment: Oh!  I see. Look at my updated answer

Comment: @KingDingeling: You should put the work you've done into the question itself, so that people don't waste time duplicating your effort or telling you things that you already know. (Writing "I have set up the arc length integral [show it], but what irritates me is the 'third quadrant' part" is *far* more helpful to prospective answerers than "I have absolutely no idea how to compute that".)

Comment: The radicand should be $(at)^2+a^2$.

Comment: Thank you. But what would be the formula for the first turn?

Comment: The first turn or the first quadrant?